# Stuck on a set proof

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I am currently working through a set proof and am stuck on the following step.

> Prove of disprove: $(R-S)-(T-U) = (R-T)-(S-U)$.

> **My attempt:**
> \begin{align*}
> \text{LHS} &= (R-S)-(T-U) \\
> &= \{x: (x\in R ∧  x\notin S) - (x\in T ∧ x\notin U)\} && \text{definition of set difference} \\
> &= \{x: (x\in R ∧  x\notin S) ∧ (x\notin T ∨ x\in U)\} && \text{De Morgan's} \\
> \end{align*}

This is as far as I can seem to get. Can anyone help me with how to go from here?

Comment: Long answer short: Having trouble *proving* something you are asked to *prove or disprove*, indicates that *maybe* you should try *disproving* instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to prove it by using ‘element-chasing’ to show that each side is a subset of the other. For instance, suppose that $x\in(R\setminus S)\setminus(T\setminus U)$; we want to show that $x\in(R\setminus T)\setminus(S\setminus U)$. We know that $x\in R$. We also know that $x\notin T\setminus U$, so either $x\notin T$, or $x\in T$ **and** $x\in U$.

If $x\notin T$, then $x\in R\setminus T$, and we just have to show that $x\notin S\setminus U$. But $x\in R\setminus S$, so $x\notin S$, and therefore $x\notin S\setminus U$, so $x\in(R\setminus T)\setminus(S\setminus U)$, as desired.

If $x\in T$ and $x\in U$, then $x\notin R\setminus T$, and therefore $x\notin(R\setminus T)\setminus(S\setminus U)$. If this can happen, the result is false, so let’s try to construct a counterexample. Let $R=\{0,1\}$, $S=\varnothing$, and $T=U=\{0\}$. Then

$$(R\setminus S)\setminus(T\setminus U)=\{0,1\}\setminus\varnothing=\{0,1\}\,,$$

but

$$(R\setminus T)\setminus(S\setminus U)=\{1\}\setminus\varnothing=\{1\}\,,$$

and the two sets are **not** equal. Thus, the theorem is actually false.

Trying to prove a result and seeing where the proof runs into trouble can point to a counterexample, as happened here.

Answer (score 1):

When asked to "prove or disprove", we should first determine whether it appears to be true or false.

You have attempted to "prove", which will not be possible if it is false, and you are having trouble.  This indicates that *maybe* you should be attempting to "disprove" instead.

Well, equality is bidirectional, so we might try to approach from both ends to (hopefully) meet somewhere in the centre -- *or* expose why we cannot.

$\begin{array}{ll|ll}
\text{LHS} &= (R\smallsetminus S)\smallsetminus (T\smallsetminus U) & \text{RHS} &=(R\smallsetminus T)\smallsetminus(S\smallsetminus U)\\&=(R \cap S^{\small\complement})\cap(T\cap U^{\small\complement})^{\small\complement}&&=(R\cap T^{\small\complement})\cap(S\cap U^{\small\complement})^{\small\complement}\\&=(R\cap S^{\small\complement})\cap(T^{\small\complement}\cup U)&&=(R\cap T^{\small\complement})\cap(S^{\small\complement}\cup U)\\&=(R\cap S^{\small\complement}\cap T^{\small\complement})\cup(R\cap S^{\small\complement}\cap U)&&=(R\cap S^{\small\complement}\cap T^{\small\complement})\cup(R\cap T^{\small\complement}\cap U)
\end{array}$

Which do not appear to be generally equal.   So we should look for a counter example.

> Let us assign $R=U$ and $S=T^{\small\complement}$, then $\text{LHS}=R\cap T$ while $\text{RHS}=R\cap T^\complement.$